# Randomly spread a dataset in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'd like to randomly spread into three a dataset with a ratio of 60%,20%,20%. I've coded something but the problem is that it can select twice the same values randomly. The code:

```
mask_60 = np.random.choice([False, True], len(ds2), p=[0.4,0.6])
mask_20 = np.random.choice([False, True], len(ds2), p=[0.8,0.2])

ds2_train = ds2[mask_60]
ds2_test = ds2[mask_20]
ds2_val = ds2[mask_20]
```

Any suggestion ?

Thanks!

Comment: you can use `np.random.shuffle' and then select the first 60%, next 20% and last 20%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sklearn's `train_test_split`, documentation [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html).  First split the dataset into 60% and 40%, then split the 40% in half.

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
set_1, temp = train_test_split(ds2, train_size=0.6, random_state=42)
set_2, set_3 = train_test_split(temp, train_size=0.5, random_state=42)
```

You can also specify a seed value to make your sample reproducible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but an error occurs by doing so:

 ValueError: Number of labels=1 does not match number of samples=75035

Comment: make sure you are passing the arrays + parameters correctly, it sounds like it might think another parameter might be the 'Y' column.  post the code somewhere and I can check it.

Comment: Below is the code I've written, maybe the error comes from this line:

train, temp = train_test_split(ds2, train_size = 0.8) #training set

test, val = train_test_split(temp, test_size=0.5) #test set, validation set

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Jonah

```
%reset
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sklearn.ensemble as sk
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer

dataset=pd.read_csv('raw_data/data_set_nass_ges_person_2014.csv',sep=";");
   ds=dataset

ds2 = ds[ds["INJ_SEV"] <=4 ] #to clean useless variables from 5 to 9 , MAXSEV_IM

train, temp = train_test_split(ds2, train_size = 0.8) #training set

test, val = train_test_split(temp, test_size=0.5) #test set, validation set

rfc = sk.RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=500, oob_score=True)

train_data = train[train.columns[1:-1]] #input
train_truth = train["INJ_SEV"] #target

train_data = Imputer().fit_transform(train_data)
train_truth = Imputer().fit_transform(train_truth) #to solve the problem of 32bit vs 64bit

model = rfc.fit(train_data, train_truth) # Here appears the problem
```